# Changes do not propagate between multiple aws instances running behind an ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, wordpress, rds

I am running wordpress behind an autoscaling group on AWS, with initial instances set to 2. It is sitting behind an ELB. A dedicated RDS instance is running for database. I am using an pre-generated custom AMI to generate new instances. Now my issue is this, whenever I change something on one instance for eg: changing some code, uploading a plugin etc. it is not propagating on other instances. What am I missing, I am new to AWS.

Comment: An elastic load balancer simply directs traffic to an instance, it does nothing to mirror server contents or file system contents. You need to use shared storage like MLu suggested. AWS has patterns for Wordpress architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Your WordPress must be on a *shared storage* mounted to both instances. Otherwise the changes will be local to the instance where you made them.

Look at **AWS Elastic File System (EFS)** for a shared storage solution.